# Can I have two users with the same name but different UID's?

Tags: users, email, uid

I have a server that I use for playing around with. I want to set up an email account that is @.com, but the way that SquirrelMail and the mail server is set up, the home folder for the username has to be stored in var/www/squirrelmail, instead of /home. Can I have two users named  with different UID's, permissions, groups, etc? I assume that Ubuntu Server will let me, but I'm worried that there could be some side effects/ security flaws. Are there?

Comment: Why not just use a symlink?

Comment: Which email server are you using?  postfix? ... if so, the mail directories are configurable.  You could place the `maildir` anywhere... and you could use `virtualmaps` so that your mail users do not need to have a user account listed in `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably not going to work because the system (the glibc) would resolve the name always to the same entry (probably the first). So it would not make a difference whether the second entry is there or not.